# How can you add additional features/attributes while doing instance segmentation?

Tags: image-segmentation, mask-rcnn

I want to do an instance segmentation of objects in images.

Usually I would stick to something like an Mask R CNN and let it run. However additionally to the image itself and the pre-labeled images, I have additional features that might be interesting for the segmentation.

Example: I want to segment certain products in images from a factory and I have additional information about the products than run at a specific time (like product family, color, brand, etc.).

How do I add these additional features in an instance segmentation?